# HQL-Select from 2 tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I am a beginner in `Hibernate`. I want to select data from two tables using `hql`.
the problem is that the query gives me result if I select one object like this example:

```
(select d from eresa  e, dresa  d where  e.f_ideResa = d.eresa.f_ideResa and e.F_DATEFROM=:x)
```

but when i want to select multiples data from 2 two tables like this :

```
(select e.f_ideResa, d.F_PAXNAME from eresa as e, dresa as d where  e.f_ideResa = d.eresa.f_ideResa and e.F_DATEFROM=:x  ");)
```

it gives me error:

> Etat HTTP 500 - java.lang.NumberFormatException..

Comment: Your should learn proper `join` syntax.  But your problem may be that you are reading `d.F_PAXNAME` as a number rather than as a string.

Comment: According to exception you must be passing wrong value which cannot be cast into number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I shoud to use arraylist instead list

```
public List<eresa> getDetailparDateArrive(Date date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    //  Query req=session.createQuery("from eresa e inner join dresa d on e.f_ideResa = d.eresa.f_ideResa and e.F_DATEFROM=:x  ");
        Query req=session.createQuery("from eresa e, dresa d where e.F_DATEFROM=:x and e.f_ideResa = d.eresa.f_ideResa ");
        req.setParameter("x", date);
        return req.list();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If both tables have relationship then use join to fetch data using join we use

```
select e.f_ideResa, d.F_PAXNAME from  eresa as e
 left join fetch e.dresa as d
where 
e.F_DATEFROM=:x "
```

`dresa` is propery in Pojo classs `eresa`
You must check `f_ideResa`,`F_PAXNAME`,`F_DATEFROM` must be field names in Pojo class

For more details [**see**](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)